# How can I reproduce a similar synth sound as in "Netzwerk" (Klangkarussell)?

Tags: synthesizer, keyboard, production, electronic-music, replication

I really like the synth sound in "Netzwerk" from Austrian Electro Producers Klangkarussell:

(especially from ~00.00-00.45)

I tried several synths (Arturia's V Collection, Sylenth, NI's synths...), analog and modern, but I didn't get close to that sound.

The change in the sound seem to be filters turnin up (?!?) but what could the basic synth sound be made with?

I guess it could be made with Arturia Prophet, but I didn't manage to do it with that.

If somebody got any clue I would be very thankful :).

Answer (score 0):

Most synths with a 24db ladder filter and a sawtooth waveform will make that sound. It’s just a case of playing about with the eg and the cutoff. A sequencer would help too.